# Passing component reference to function

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I would like to know that how can we pass variable of the component to the function? Like below:

```
// here is the function that I want to pass 'winArticle' by parameter
var getLevels = function(win) {
    return win.down('fieldset[id=article-fieldset]').items.items.length;
}

var winArticle = new Ext.Window({
   ...

handler : function() {
    // I tried this but nothing happen
    getLevels('winArticle');
}
});
```

Comment: Your question doesn't have enough information. Where is the handler declared in relation to the window? `winArticle` is already a reference to the window object, so you just pass that.

Comment: Dear Evan, there are 5 windows like this so that I want to pass window variable to the function. It doesn't matter `handler`, just wanted to write simple sample. `getLevels` function declared in top of script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments I'm not sure where there is any confusion, you already have a reference to the window, so just pass it.

```
var myWin = new Ext.window.Window();
someMethod(myWin);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add an itemId for the component and from the scope you can always use down or up functions to get the component.

If you want to pass in the component as arguments to the function, its seems that you are calling the function from the component you want to pass, so just do **this** as an argument which would pass the component in the function. Make sure to set the scope for the handler component.

Modifying your code would be some thing like this

```
var winArticle = new Ext.Window({
...
{
  xtype: 'button',
  scope: this,
  handler : function() {
     getLevels(this);
  } 
}
});
```